# UINT32 compiler version mismatch - Linking to legacy library

Tags: c++, linker, uint32

I am trying to link a DLL but I am constantly running into issues with `UINT32`.

The library is compiled against the 4.1 version of the Visual Studio compiler. The interface for my component (which was 4.1 and I am now porting to 2012) is defined with many `UINT32`s in it. In VC4.1 `UINT32` is not defined by the compiler and so it was typedefed to `unsigned long` by the programmer, but from VC6 onwards `UINT32` is defined as `unsigned int`. This makes my life hard.

My initial reaction was to try replacing all `UINT32` in the interface with `unsigned long` and recompiling. This works as the function signatures are the same. However an `unsigned long` in 2012 is 64 bits wide... not 32 bits. This is not a problem in most cases but I foresee possible problems with flag parameters and return types.

What I am wondering is if I have missed a more obvious solution for this. I thought of defining a different type

```
typedef OAM_UINT32 unsigned long //in the library
typedef OAM_UINT32 unsigned int // in my component
```

But then the problem is going to be the same as what I have already with my two definitions of UINT32... right?

Any help would be much appreciated.

**The Problem**

Client code

```
#include <oam_if.h>
....
UINT32 uuid = getSomeLocalUserId();
UINT32 dwOamRetVal = dwOamGetUserDetails( uuid ); // LINK ERROR: Symbol not found
```

oam_if.h

```
UINT32 dwOamGetUserDetails( UINT32 idOfUser );
```

When the library (OAM) is compiled the UINT32 value is evaluated as an `unsigned long`. When the client component is compiled, UINT32 is evaluated as `unsigned int`. The linker complains because it has a symbol defined in the OAM library for `dwOamGetuserDetails` which rakes and returns an `unsigned long`, but the client is calling a function which according to it should take an `unsigned int`.

So while their respective inputs are unsigned numbers both 32 bits long, the signature of the function is different and the linker complains.

The only way I can see to fix it is to define everything as `unsigned long` directly. However then OAM will be using a 32 bit long number but the client will be using a 64 bit number!

**Sample of Linker Error**

> error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual unsigned long __thiscall Message::getCallId(void)const " (?getCallId@Message@@UBEKXZ) oam.lib(OAM_SsRequest.obj)

This is actually a callback from the library to the component, so in this case it is looking for a signature that matches UINT32 as defined by the libary (unsigned long) but the component is defining an unsigned int for its callback.

Comment: The solution would be to use `uint32_t` from `<stdint>`, and finally kick Microsoft into supporting C99...

Comment: I assume that you would be making this change in the header for the library. My concern would be more of the CRT used in the .DLL. If it was dynamically linked to VC 4.1 you may run into serious problems with memory allocation / deallocation.

Comment: Doing this "double" typedef, where one part uses unsigned long and the other unsigned int should work with no problems and decouples you from the Windows-based types. It's unclear to me why you need to continue compiling the library against such an old version of Visual Studio. Have you considered porting it forward to a more modern version of the compiler?

Comment: @NikB. Yes porting it forward would be the ideal solution, but the component is owned by another team, and I'm pretty sure that they won't port it forward. However when you say that the double typedef should work, is that true? At the minute `UINT32` is typedefed in the library as `long` and in the application as `int` but that doesn't work.

Comment: I figured that was going to be the reasoning... Yes, it should work *assuming* that both types have the same width (e.g. 4 bytes) and are both signed or both unsigned. When you say it doesn't work, can you elaborate? What, *specifically*, fails?

Comment: @NikB. I get linker errors regarding symbols defined in the library headers which are not found in the library. See the original post. Will update now

Comment: Can you post the exact linker error message please? Also, how are you declaring these functions in the application - including a library header file or re-declaring them all yourself?

Comment: Ah, you are using C++ and the library interface is *also* in C++? This is likely to cause all sorts of weird, if for no other reason because of potentially different name mangling. I don't know that this is something that you can easily solve.